# Doesn't write data to database | SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

When I try save a String like `IupSH6M1e6FteCm30IQv9hTyxr7quFFFFFZuHjCe`in my Database it's doesn't work (string doesn't write to DB).

This is the `DDL` of sqlite table:

```
  CREATE TABLE [settings] (
  [id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  [key] TEXT, 
  [value] TEXT);
```

This is my code for writing a String to this table:

```
public void setProperty(String key, String value) {
    db.delete(SETTINGS_TABLE_NAME, "key='" + key + "'", null); // clear old data
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put("key", key);
    initialValues.put("value", value);
    db.insert(SETTINGS_TABLE_NAME, null, initialValues);
}
```

But the string doesn't write to the Database. 
Why?

Comment: Do any strings get saved? Did you call getWritableDatabase() to get the database (i.e. it's not read-only)?

Comment: SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_SET, null, values);
        db.close();

Comment: `key` is a SQLite keyword, try a different column name

Comment: @LordRaydenMK `key` is accepted here.

Comment: The code shown looks OK. Are you sure it is executed? How do you determine whether it is in the database?